# Passing value from Jquery event to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application.I am replacing a existing table control only (JQuery html coded) with AngularJS grid.
I want to pass id value to AngularJs app from jQuery click event. On click event below code is not working.Please suggest the right way to pass the value.Using angular.element is not working.

```
$(".bs-example").on('click', '#alldiv a', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            // This id is required to use in angular app 
            angular.element($("#my-table")).scope().getData();
});


var myApp = angular.module('myGrid', ['ngTable']);
            myApp.controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'services', 'NgTableParams', function (scope, http, ser, NgTableParams) {
                ser.getData().success(function (response) {
                    scope.agendas = response;
                    scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({ page: 1, count: 2 }, { dataset: scope.mydata });
                });
                scope.mydata = {
                    data: 'mydata'
                }
            }]);
            myApp.service('services', function ($http) {

                this.getData = function () {
                    // Need id from button jQuery click event
                    var result = $http.get('/Home/GetData/' + id);
                    return result;
                };
            });



<div data-ng-app="myGrid" data-ng-controller="gridCtrl" id="my-table">
//.....
</div
```

Comment: create a method in your controller that accepts the `id` -- say, `loadGrid(id)` and then pass that same id to `getData()`.  Then change your `angular.element` statement to `angular.element($("#my-table")).scope().loadGrid(id)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
EDIT:

```
 $(".bs-example").on('click', '#alldiv a', function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                   //HEre you pass a id to angular controller.
                   angular.element($("#my-table")).scope().getData(id);
        });





         var myApp = angular.module('myGrid', ['ngTable']);
                    myApp.controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'services', 'NgTableParams', function (scope, http, ser, NgTableParams) {
                        $scope.GetData = function(id) {
                         ser.getData(id).success(function (response) {
                            scope.agendas = response;
                            scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({ page: 1, count: 2 }, { dataset: scope.mydata });
                        });
}
                        scope.mydata = {
                            data: 'mydata'
                        }
                    }]);
                    myApp.service('services', function ($http) {

    //Add to this function parameter 
                        this.getData = function (id) { //here declare that this function 
                            // Need id from button jQuery click event
                            var result = $http.get('/Home/GetData/' + id);
                            return result;
                        };
                    });
```

IHMO better option here will be use a ng-click angular method on the div that you wana click.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: `getData` won't be in the scope of `my-table` though since it's not a method declared in the controller, right?

Comment: I make Edit to code becouse first time i missunderstand you. 
There can be a bracket problems becouse this stack editor isn't "code friendly".

Comment: @Ridikk12 I have tried your code but getting the error as "Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).getData is not a function" under jQuery click event

Comment: @Ridikk12 I do not want to change existing ASP.NET MVC application code to Angular ( like using ng-click) from where click event is generated.I am aiming just to replace one or two control with AngularJS as per the requirement

Comment: It's work.
Change  angular.element($("#my-table")).scope().getData(id);
to  angular.element($("#my-table")).scope().GetData(id);

Function in controller is called GetData :)

Answer (score -1):

I am able to call Angular function from JQuery with following code

```
$(".bs-example").on('click', '#alldiv a', function () {
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
             var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("my-table")).scope();
             scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.save(id);
            });
});
```